# Is there a way to control what browser plugins are installed across an enterprise?

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

Is there a way to control what browser plugins are installed across an enterprise, perhaps by group policy?

Comment: Which browser? Firefox? Chrome? Seamonkey? Windows? Linux? Mac OS?

Comment: Any browser would be fine. I am looking for a general solution to inventory and control what extensions get installed across the enterprise.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say Group Policy, I'm going to assume Windows.

You can install Firefox through Group Policy if you create an msi to do so with a third party tool (such as [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/)), or by creating a script that executes the [full rather than stub installer](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/) (`c:\path\to\firefox-full-install.exe -ms`), or by using a [Firefox ESR deployment](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Deployment:Deploying_Firefox).  You can then install plugins with a script that runs `c:\path\to\firefox.exe c:\path\to\plugins\*.xpi`.

Google Chrome [provides an MSI](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?msi=true) specifically to make it easier to deploy through Group Policy.  They also provide a framework (a [master preferences file](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187948)) for pushing settings and [group policy templates](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates) that you can use to install extensions.  [You can also use the master preferences file to install extensions](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453?hl=en).

Comment: I really appreciate all your help. Its a great way to deploy browsers across the enterprise but I wonder if there is a way to track and inventory exactly what toolbars and extensions my end users installed themselves? Is there a way to prevent endusers from installing toolbars? I wonder if I can query my enterprise network to get a report of what extensions are installed where. This will help me mitigate browser threats.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Internet Explorer, you can use the Add-on Management policies in Group Policy, found in `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Security Features > Add-on Management`, specifically the Add-on List Policy, which allows you to specify the CLSID of each individual extension to be approved.

You're not going to find a pretty way to manage other (non-Microsoft) browser add-ons with group policy. If the browser stores it's add-on list in the registry, you can possibly manipulate it through Group Policy registry. Regardless, unless you have a good reason to run a browser other than IE (for example, if you have in-house web designers that need multiple browsers), you should take advantage of the extensive management features that you gain access to by using IE and Group Policy.